# Wrap element(s) with a new tag determined by the total of their attribute values

Tags: xml, xslt

When transforming the following XML instance;

**source.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<indd xmlns:aid="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/4.0/" xmlns:aid5="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/5.0/">
  <article>
    <table aid5:tablestyle="my-table" aid:trows="10" aid:tcols="4">
      <cell aid:theader="" aid:ccols="3">Head A</cell>
      <cell aid:theader="" aid:ccols="1">Head B</cell>
      <cell aid:ccols="2">A</cell>
      <cell aid:ccols="1">B</cell>
      <cell aid:ccols="1">C</cell>
      <cell aid:ccols="4"></cell>
      <cell aid:ccols="1">E</cell>
      <cell aid:ccols="1">F</cell>
      <cell aid:ccols="1">G</cell>
      <cell aid:ccols="1">H</cell>
      <cell aid:ccols="1">I</cell>
      <cell aid:ccols="1">J</cell>
      <cell aid:ccols="1">K</cell>
      <cell aid:ccols="1">L</cell>
      <cell aid:ccols="1">M</cell>
      <cell aid:ccols="1">N</cell>
      <cell aid:ccols="1">O</cell>
      <cell aid:ccols="1">P</cell>
      <cell aid:ccols="1">Q</cell>
      <cell aid:ccols="1">R</cell>
      <cell aid:ccols="1">S</cell>
      <cell aid:ccols="1">T</cell>
      <cell aid:ccols="1">U</cell>
      <cell aid:ccols="1">V</cell>
      <cell aid:ccols="1">W</cell>
      <cell aid:ccols="1">X</cell>
      <cell aid:ccols="1">Y</cell>
      <cell aid:ccols="3">Z</cell>
    </table>
  </article>
</indd>
```

using the following XSLT (1.0);

**transform.xsl**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:aid="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/4.0/"
  xmlns:aid5="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/5.0/"
  exclude-result-prefixes="aid aid5"
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="indd/article/table[@aid5:tablestyle='my-table']">
    <table>
      <xsl:attribute name="class">
        <xsl:value-of select="@aid5:tablestyle"/>
      </xsl:attribute>

      <xsl:for-each select="cell">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="@aid:theader=''">
            <th>
              <xsl:attribute name="colspan">
                <xsl:value-of select="@aid:ccols"/>
              </xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </th>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <td>
              <xsl:attribute name="colspan">
                <xsl:value-of select="@aid:ccols"/>
              </xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </td>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It produces the following output:

**result.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<table class="my-table">
   <th colspan="3">Head A</th>
   <th colspan="1">Head B</th>
   <td colspan="2">A</td>
   <td colspan="1">B</td>
   <td colspan="1">C</td>
   <td colspan="4"/>
   <td colspan="1">E</td>
   <td colspan="1">F</td>
   <td colspan="1">G</td>
   <td colspan="1">H</td>
   <td colspan="1">I</td>
   <td colspan="1">J</td>
   <td colspan="1">K</td>
   <td colspan="1">L</td>
   <td colspan="1">M</td>
   <td colspan="1">N</td>
   <td colspan="1">O</td>
   <td colspan="1">P</td>
   <td colspan="1">Q</td>
   <td colspan="1">R</td>
   <td colspan="1">S</td>
   <td colspan="1">T</td>
   <td colspan="1">U</td>
   <td colspan="1">V</td>
   <td colspan="1">W</td>
   <td colspan="1">X</td>
   <td colspan="1">Y</td>
   <td colspan="3">Z</td>
</table>
```

#### Desired Result

However, my requirement is the transform `source.xml` to produce the following:

**wanted.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<table class="my-table">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="3">Head A</th>
    <th colspan="1">Head B</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">A</td>
    <td colspan="1">B</td>
    <td colspan="1">C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4"/>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="1">E</td>
    <td colspan="1">F</td>
    <td colspan="1">G</td>
    <td colspan="1">H</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="1">I</td>
    <td colspan="1">J</td>
    <td colspan="1">K</td>
    <td colspan="1">L</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="1">M</td>
    <td colspan="1">N</td>
    <td colspan="1">O</td>
    <td colspan="1">P</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="1">Q</td>
    <td colspan="1">R</td>
    <td colspan="1">S</td>
    <td colspan="1">T</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="1">U</td>
    <td colspan="1">V</td>
    <td colspan="1">W</td>
    <td colspan="1">X</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="1">Y</td>
    <td colspan="3">Z</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Currently *transform.xsl* does not transform *source.xml* to include the necessary `tr` elements that are present in *wanted.xml*.

#### Question

Is it possible to use XSLT (1.0) to include the necessary `tr` elements as shown in *wanted.xml*?

As you can see, the values of the `aid:ccols` attributes for each `cell` element that is present in *source.xml* could be utilized to inform the transformation as to when the resultant `th` or `td` element(s) should be wrapped in `tr` elements. Essentially it's when consecutive `aid:ccols` values total 4 as per the value of the `table` elements `aid:tcols="4"` attribute in *source.xml*.

For example:

- Consider the first two `cell` elements at positions 1 and 2 in *source.xml*. Their total value of `aid:ccols` attributes is 4 (3 + 1), therefore their resulant `th` elements should be wrapped with an opening and closing `tr` tag.
- Consider `cell` elements in *source.xml* at positions 3,4, and 5. Their total value of `aid:ccols` attributes is 4 (2 + 1 + 1) therefore their resulant `th` elements should be wrapped with an opening and closing `tr` tag.
- Consider the `cell` element in *source.xml* at positions 6. Its `aid:ccols` value already totals 4 therefore its resultant `th` element should be wrapped with an opening and closing `tr` tag.

Comment: You can use a technique call sibling recursion in XSLT 1 to start processing the first `cell` element with a parameter for the wanted number and check if the parameter has the value (e.g. 4), then output the wrapper `tr` and the collected `cell`s, otherwise process the next sibling, passing on the current `cell` in another parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, you want to do something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:aid5="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/5.0/"
xmlns:aid="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/4.0/"
exclude-result-prefixes="aid5 aid">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="table">
    <table class="{@aid5:tablestyle}">
        <tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="cell[@aid:theader]">
                <th colspan="{@aid:ccols}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </th>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
        <xsl:call-template name="body">
            <xsl:with-param name="cells" select="cell[not(@aid:theader)]"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="target-width" select="@aid:tcols"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="body">
    <xsl:param name="cells"/>
    <xsl:param name="target-width"/>
    <xsl:param name="row" select="/.."/>
    <xsl:param name="width" select="0"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$width >= $target-width">
            <tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="$row">
                    <td colspan="{@aid:ccols}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </td>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
            <!-- recursive call -->
            <xsl:call-template name="body">
                <xsl:with-param name="cells" select="$cells"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="target-width" select="$target-width"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="row" select="/.."/>
                <xsl:with-param name="width" select="0"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$cells">
            <xsl:variable name="cell" select="$cells[1]" />
            <xsl:call-template name="body">
                <xsl:with-param name="cells" select="$cells[position() > 1]"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="target-width" select="$target-width"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="row" select="$row | $cell"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="width" select="$width + $cell/@aid:ccols"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Another possible approach is a technique known as *"sibling recursion"* (look it up). Though the basic principle is same.

Comment: I presume line #29 that reads `<xsl:when test="$width >= 4">` is key to determine when consecutive `aid:ccols` values total 4 and therefore wrap `td` element(s) with a `tr` tag accordingly. If that’s the case Is there a way to reference the value of the `table` elements `aid:tcols` attribute in _source.xml_ rather than hardcore the `4` on line #29 ?

Comment: It actually determines whether the values accumulated in the `$row` buffer have  reached or exceeded 4. But yes, of course you can use a value taken from the input XML instead of hardcoding a minimum. I have edited my answer to include this.